# Turn off field separator and a simple query

Tags: postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
www.a.com | site a
www.b.net | site b
www.c.com | site c
```

I'de like to save it into a file (I use \o for it) in a the following format:

```
  - www.a.com: *def      # site a
  - www.b.net: *def      # site b
  - www.c.com: *def      # site c
```

What is query can I use to make this file format (*def and # sign are fixed and not stored in the database). I think I should turn off field separator(vertical bar character) between fields of a row for this.
Any idea?

Comment: psql is not a general text processor.  Pipe the output to perl or sed or something similar.

Comment: I think my question has nothing to do with text processing, it is just a query on database where the result is formatted a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select everything as a single column:

```
select '  - '||column_1||': *def      # '||column_2
from the table`
```

Comment: What about this approach `select format(' - %s: *def      # %s','www.a.com','site a')`?